# TCXO Frequencies below 10MHz

Tags: crystal, tcxo

why are there no TCXOs for 8MHz? Does this not work technically or are they not used at that frequency?
The lowest I can find is 10Mhz.
Thank you.

Comment: Suntsu, ECS and others make TCXOs below 10 MHz. Are you looking for a specific package size?

Comment: Also consider dividing the frequency down; flip-flop for instance.

Comment: No specific package size. Thanks for the hint

Comment: There are some TCXOs at the ECS website that are listed starting below 8Mhz, but they really only have them starting at 10Mhz. Suntsu looks more promising, though.

Answer (score 1):

[TCXO's start at 32kHz and up  so use a better distributor.](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/oscillators/172?s=N4IgjCBcpgHAzFUBjKAzAhgGwM4FMAaEAeygG0QAWMABgDYAmOkAXSIAcAXKEAZU4BOASwB2AcxABfIgFoGSEKkiCAroRLkQAVlYdukEFOkh5kCp2QAPUmxDNoIIQBMeDMFpog9PAKoihnADyaACyeBg4KgJ4XiCcAJ7sMQYRqJKSQA)

Comment: I agree with you that there are actually TCXO's below 10Mhz, so my research was insufficient. However, there are very few and I haven't found one with 8Mhz that is in stock.

Answer (score 0):

Follow up to my question: As ScienceGeyser said in the comments, Suntsu offers TCXOs below 10Mhz. I was told by different suppliers that it is currently hard to get any TCXOs due to a fire in a factory. Source below.
https://www.strata-gee.com/akm-fire-2020-was-almost-over-then-disaster-struck-again/